# How to understand the formal analysis of quickselect?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, quicksort, selection-problem

According to various informal analysis, we know that the running time of quickselect is o(n), by assuming thay the partition is always taking half of the array. However, my lecture gives without proof that if we do a formal analysis, we will get the following formula:

$$C_N = 2 N + 2 k ln (N / k) + 2 (N – k) ln (N / (N – k))$$

*$C_n$ is the number of compares if the array has N items.

Does anyone know how this formula is derived?

Comment: How do you get o(n) rather than O(n)? $\;$

Comment: "we know that the running time of quickselect is o(n), by assuming thay the partition is always taking half of the array." -- No, we don't. We show that the *expected* runtime it in $O(n)$ by *showing* that (in the random permutation model) we get rid of half the values *in expectation*. Are you familiar with the principles of average-case analysis?

Comment: 1. Please provide more context.  What's $k$?  What's $C_N$?  Is $C_N$ the expected number of comparisons, the worst-case number of comparisons, or something else?  2. What research have you done?  Have you done some searching to look for lecture notes on QuickSelect?  Have you looked at standard algorithms textbooks?  Many algorithms textbooks, and many online resources, give a detailed explanation of the analysis of running time of QuickSelect.

Comment: 3. In fact, [the Wikipedia article on QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) links to [an analysis of QuickSelect's running time](http://11011110.livejournal.com/119720.html), which happens to give a similar (but not identical) formula and to explain where each term came from. Does that analysis help with your question?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and to show us in the question what you've done. [Generally, if the answer can be found by going to the obvious place on Wikipedia, you need to do more research before asking.]

Comment: k is the index of the pivot. CLRS and algorithms by kevin wayne both do not have an analysis. Thats why i am asking. And i don't quite understand the article you linked. I ask here because I am looking for an easy to understand analysis, or intuition, even if it does not list the exact analysis. @D.W.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify these points -- don't just drop clarifications in the comment thread.  People should be able to understand everything they need to know, just from reading your question.  If you don't understand that article, what specifically don't you understand?  What's the first sentence you don't understand?  If you can't understand anything of it, then you might not have the prerequisites/math background to understand this kind of runtime analysis, and your next step might be to go back to the basics and spend some quality time studying basics of runtime analysis.